# Running total in Google Sheets leaving blank cells if criteria not met

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I would like to keep a running total in column A if certain text is present in column B. If that text isn't present, I would like column A to be blank, but pick up counting where it left off on the next time the criteria is met.

Example: When column B contains blue, yellow, or red, count in column A, lest leave blank

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue |
| 2 | yellow |
|  | green |
|  | orange |
| 3 | blue |
|  | green |
| 4 | red |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the color names are in column B2:B, use `countifs()` like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    regexmatch(B2:B, "^(blue|yellow|red)$"), 
    countifs( 
      row(B2:B), "<=" & row(B2:B), 
      regexextract(B2:B & "µ", "(?:blue|yellow|red)(µ)"), "µ" 
    ), 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: I tried that and updated it to fit my exact search and I received an Error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A2"

Comment: The formula in the answer is an array formula that fills the _whole column_ automatically. Clear column A before you insert the formula to make room for the results.

Comment: I'm realizing now that I completely messed up my question looking back at my sheet. Here is my document if you're willing to assist further. I'm a baseball coach creating a pitch tracking document. So after a result, I want to start a new batter, hence the counting. However, the running total would be on the next row down.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HbMsMufJLRJrFQFrAXkkJ3EhXnHHRM4OELBL8i7fiWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, that is a different question. Please post it separately. Show your _hand-entered_ expected results in the sample spreadsheet.

Comment: I'll do that right now. Thank you.